# Cannot run with sound null safety, Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

After updating
environment:
sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

This problem appeared to me :-

Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
don't support null safety:

- package:splashscreen
- package:hijri
  2

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Unsupported Null Safety mode NonNullableByDefaultCompiledMode.Invalid, in null.
#0      ProgramCompiler.emitModule (package:dev_compiler/src/kernel/compiler.dart:435:9)

#1      JavaScriptBundler.compile (package:frontend_server/src/javascript_bundle.dart:144:33)
#2      FrontendCompiler.writeJavascriptBundle (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:632:20)

#3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:545:9)

#4      listenAndCompile. (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1105:11)

the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Failed to compile application.
Exited (sigterm)

Answer (score 1):

The libraries are not Null Safety yet, use sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: I want this version 2.12.0 <3.0.0 ,to solve a problem ..  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key); .. in "?"

Comment: I think you cannot use that libraries with null safety